# How to add a body class to all interior pages except the homepage

Tags: css, homepage

I want to add a class to the body tag to all pages EXCEPT the homepage. Right now I have.

`<?php body_class('interior'); ?>`

But it adds 'interior' to ALL pages including the home page.

What is the best standard way of adding a class to the body tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it:

```
<?php
$class = ! is_home() ? "interior" : "";
body_class( $class );
?>
```

Or this:

```
<?php
body_class( ! is_home() ? "interior" : "" );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! however it still adds interior to the 'home' page as well.

Comment: Oddly, worked here.

Comment: Try it: <body <?php body_class( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() ? "interior" : "" ); ?>>

Comment: I adjusted my reading settings to static and have no pages selected & it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The filter [**`body_class`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) can be used for this.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_wpse_85793', 10, 2 );

function body_class_wpse_85793( $classes, $class )
{
    // This one overrides all original classes
    if( is_home() )
        $classes = array( 'interior' );

    // This one simply adds a new class
    //if( is_home() )
    //  $classes[] = 'interior';

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: very nice.  One more reason not to copy header.php down into my child template directory if I don't need to make additional modifications to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `body_class` filter to add any class to the body tag in WordPress.

Add the below code to your functions.php file.

**Add class to the body tag for all the pages.**

```
    add_filter('body_class', 'wp_body_class');
function wp_body_class($class)
{
  $class[] = 'my-custom-class'; // Add your class name here. Multiple class names can be added 'classname1 classname2'.
  return $class;
}
```

**Exclude Home Page**

```
if (!is_front_page() ) { // exclude home or any other page.
add_filter('body_class', 'wp_body_class');
}

function wp_body_class($class)
{
  $class[] = 'my-custom-class'; // Add your class name here. Multiple class names can be added 'classname1 classname2'.
  return $class;
}
```